# JSTL fmt how to format date like "yy"

Tags: java, date, formatting, jstl

I want to get a short year representation - "19" instead of "2019". How can it do that?

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${tempDate}" pattern="yyyy"/>
```

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=date+pattern+jstl) led me to the truth, but I won't disclose it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer

```java
<fmt:formatDate value="${tempDate}" pattern="yy"/>
```

#### Wh`yy`?

Thanks to @gurioso for pointing out the JSTL spec [here](https://www.w3processing.com/index.php?subMenuLoad=JSP/JSTL/FormattingJSTL.php).

> **Attribute:** Patttern
>
> **Required:** No
>
> **Description:** Custom formatting pattern for dates and times. The patterns are specified by the `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class. See table below.

The table clarifies that `y` means year, and that by using the `y` argument is is possible to get formats like "2019" or "19".

This functionality is further detailed in the [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year).

> For formatting, **if the number of pattern letters is 2, the year is truncated to 2 digits**; otherwise it is interpreted as a number.

Thus `yyyy` produces "19", while `yy` produces "2019".

Comment: My guess too. Surprised that OP did not try.

Comment: Just found confirmation that this works in the SimpleDateFormat javadoc. Updated answer.

Comment: And I found the [format spec](https://www.google.com/search?q=date+pattern+jstl). @MichaelNoguera, your link goes to the shunned SimpleDateFormat spec, take [this one](https://www.w3processing.com/index.php?subMenuLoad=JSP/JSTL/FormattingJSTL.php) for jstl.